# Stable TCP connection when hosting is starting it

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

im currently making an application where a host makes a TCP connection to me sends me some data, then i read it and send some other data back, but after that (10 seconds) my host informs me that "TCP connection timeout". Its not alot of info but im about 90% sure that its beacuse im not creating a stable TCP connection and im somehow closing it, since im just listening and creating a network stream, but im hoping someone abit more experienced in TCP can be my savior

my code:

```
        public static void ExampleForStackOverFlow()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("10.100.202.15"), 52000);
        listener.AllowNatTraversal(true);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client accepted." + listener.Pending());
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            IPEndPoint FLEXSERVER = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("request Translated: ");
                RespondForStackOverFlow(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong. " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RespondForStackOverFlow(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        
        try
        {
            stream.Write(DataToSend, 0, DataToSend.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending data");
            stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong. " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Send a dummy message, say, every 5 minutes if nothing else needs to go over the wire.

Comment: _[RFC 1122, Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122.html)_, Section 4.2.3.6  TCP Keep-Alives.